# Using Euler's Theorem with homogenous degree zero functions to simplify total differential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a proof which I'm trying to work through in an economics paper. Part of the proof relies on the following result:

- Let $F(x,y(x))$ be homogenous of degree zero in $x$, and let $y$ be homogenous of degree zero in $x$ (where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N, F:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$). Then the total change in $F$ induced through changes in $y$ sum to zero through Euler's theorem.

I'm having trouble obtaining this result. The total derivative is

$dF_i(x,y(x))=\sum_{j} \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}dx_j + \sum_{k} \sum_{j} \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial y_k} \frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_j} dx_j$

So the statement says that the second term should sum to zero.

By Euler's theorem, since $F$ is homogenous of degree zero in $x$ and $y$ is homogenous of degree zero in $x$, we know that

- $0=\sum_{j} \frac{\partial F_i(x,y(x))}{\partial x_j}x_j$ holds $\forall i$
- $0=\sum_{j} \frac{\partial y_k(x)}{\partial x_j}x_j$  holds $\forall k$

I'm unsure whether the statement needs both that $F$ and $y$ are homogenous in $x$, or whether it suffices for just $F$ to be (I don't think so), but I haven't manage to prove the statement under either assumption.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The last term in  expression for $dF_i(x,y(x))$ can be re-written as $\sum_k \sum_j \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial y_k} \frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_j} dx_j=\sum_k \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial y_k} \underbrace{\sum_j  \frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_j} dx_j}_{=0\forall k}=0$. So, only homogeneity of degree zero of $y(x)$ w.r.t $x$ is required.